# IE not loading all page requests

Tags: laravel, internet-explorer, vue.js

I'm trying to debug why my site is failing to load properly on IE 11. On chrome my home page makes an api call (I'm using Laravel backend and Vuejs with axios in the front end) to fetch all the users however, when I load the page in IE 11 no users appear, no api call is made (in the network tab on the developer tools) and there are no errors showing in the developer tools console.

Can anyone give me any tips as to how I can start debugging this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your code for the axios call and how that's triggered in vue.js (mount for example?).

Comment: Thanks for the question, it is good to know that my answer is not the only one available here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to polyfill for ie11 as mentioned on this issue on the axios github repo: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/586

> **Promises**
>
> axios depends on a native ES6 Promise implementation to be supported. If your environment doesn't support ES6 Promises, you can polyfill.

https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#promises

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. FYI ie 11 is the last version of ie so it may not support modern features like promises etc. Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) is the last version of the Internet Explorer web browser by Microsoft. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer, I have my way doing this so, check out my answer too.The other thing is I wanted to ask you opinion on is - what is better `babel-polyfill` or `es6-promise`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add babel version for promises support like so:

```
$ npm install --save babel-polyfill
```

It is not a transpiler, that is used during "compilation", but it is actually  needs to be in your mix to make your promises and axios work.

So, you go to a file `\resources\assets\js\app.js`
and add `babel-polyfill` like so:

```
require("babel-polyfill");
```

Then `npm run development` or what is your favourite script from `package.json` to build staff and enjoy.

And it was not your fault, it is a designed by Laravel creators. They actually by default include axios in to the mix but not include babel-polyfill, to make all IE users struggle and all the developers to learn that Microsoft internet Explorer does not keep promises. :)